# Restart Android Started Service after application was killed

Tags: android, xamarin, android-service

I'm trying to do a StartedService in android to send periodically the user location to a server. 
Until this moment I managed to create the service and starting it from the 'parent ' application and I don't know how to keep it alive after the application was killed. From what I found on internet the 'StartCommandResult.Sticky' should restart the service if this one is killed but from some reason this is not restarted.

I overried the OnStartCommand:

```
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        locationTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            //stuff to do
        });
        locationTask.Start();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

And the service is started like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, Class.FromType(typeof(LocationService)));
    this.Activity.StartService(intent);
```

Any suggestions what should I do in order to keep my service alive after the application was killed?

As observation I'm using xamarin to do it, but I won't mind an answer in android(java).

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an
>   activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service
>   can run in the background **indefinitely, even if the component that
>   started it is destroyed.** Usually, a started service performs a
>   single operation and does not return a result to the caller. For
>   example, it might download or upload a file over the network. When the
>   operation is done, the service should stop itself.

So, starting the service like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Will have your service running even while your app is destroyed.

Regarding Service.START_STICKY in the official documentation:

> If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns,
>   recreate the service and call onStartCommand(), but do not redeliver
>   the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand() with a
>   null intent, unless there were pending intents to start the service,
>   in which case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable for media
>   players (or similar services) that are not executing commands, but
>   running indefinitely and waiting for a job.

Comment: StartCommandResult.Sticky is the equivalent of Service.START_STICKY in xamarin. So that's not the problem I think.

Comment: As of the documentation, your `Service` are supposed to run indefinitely. Are you really sure that it's not running? How are you checking? @AlexStefan

Comment: Well I check on server if the location it's still send after the application is killed, and it is not.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to check it? @Marcus

Comment: For debugging, start a simple work thread and print out something every 5 seconds. I have never been in contact with Xamarin, but above answer works for my android application. @AlexStefan

Comment: I'm using visual studio for debug and if I kill the app, the debug session goes with it. I'll try to find a way to prints somewhere somehow, not aware of any way to do that now.

Comment: Ah, so it might be that Visual Studio kills the service because your session gets killed. I would explore if there's a way to destroy your service parent activity, without destroying your Visual Studio session. Then, I'm sure that your issue will be solved.

Comment: I investigated more this problem and it seem's that the service stays alive but somehow the task from it get's paused or something and when i start again the app it resume the task and also start a new one. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I said I'm not experienced with using Xamarin. You should update your question (specially the title) or post a new question specifically pointing out this particular issue. @AlexStefan

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it but its in JAVA code.

in your service you should implement a `LocalBinder`, `onStartCommand` and `onCreate` methods.

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    ServiceName getService() {
        return ServiceName .this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The onStartCommand should `return START_STICKY;`. And also, include this code on your Service:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);
}
```

This will restart your Service on 1 second from the time you close it. Also, dont forget to add your service in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".ServiceName"
             android:exported="false"
             android:stopWithTask="false" >
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Override onStartCommand like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, everything in the code was right but the problem was with the use of **debugging** while checking if the service was on. When I use a release version (or just dev version without connecting to the debug), the process is not killed and the service is running normally.

No idea why though. I am using Xamarin Studio 6.0.

Comment: just i need a help background services code can be written in xmarain.forms cross platform if yes any chance if u have any sample example can u please provide me